# Combining Coroutines and Reflection in Unity

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to figure out how can I combine **StartCoroutine()** with **methodInfo.Invoke()** in Unity.

First, the very basic, explicit calls code which I'd like to avoid:

```
if (ACTION_MOVE == action) {
    StartCoroutine(robotBehaviour.move());
}
else if (ACTION_ROTATE == action) {
    StartCoroutine(robotBehaviour.rotate());
}
...
```

The called methods look like this:

```
public override IEnumerator move()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
        // Do something
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(N);
    }
}
```

So with a little bit of reflection, I managed to make the call dynamically:

```
RobotBehaviour robotBehaviour = getRobotBehaviour()
Type type = robotBehaviour.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod((string)sentences[lineNo]);
result = methodInfo.Invoke(robotBehaviour, null);
```

However, now I can't manage to invoke **robotBehaviour** with **StartCoroutine()**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. What I needed to do is to tell the robotBehaviour to start the coroutine:

```
RobotBehaviour robotBehaviour = getRobotBehaviour()
Type type = robotBehaviour.GetType();
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod((string)sentences[lineNo]);
robotBehaviour.StartCoroutine(methodInfo.Name, 0);  // <-- Solved!
```